# Adding a button to TTTable View Item

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, three20

I have been banging my head on adding a button to a cell. This is what I have done.

I subclassed TTTableMessageItem and TTTableMessageItemCell.

I added the following method to the Message Item init :

```
 + (id)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title caption:(NSString *)caption text:(NSString *)text timestamp:(NSDate *)timestamp imageURL:(NSString *)imageURL URL:(NSString *)URL target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
```

I also added a SEL variable and "id" for action and target.

Under setObject in message Item Cell I added this :

```
 - (void)setObject:(id)object {
  if (_item != object) {
      [super setObject:object];

    TJTableMessageItem* item = object;

    if (item.plusAction) {
        self.plusAction = item.plusAction;
    }

    if (item.plusTarget) {
        self.plusTarget = item.plusTarget;
    }
  }
}
```

I am now able to trigger easily a method inside my datasource for the tableview. But I am not able to find out which cell was pressed. I hope someone can help me, I have spent way to much time figuring out the setObject part.

I would like to know how and add a subview like the Facebook app has, the Like, Comment part. I think I need to be able to run a method inside the view controller. But I can't find anything anywhere.  The Cybersam blog has an explanation that doesn't use the TableItem and TableItemCell like Three20 puts things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that the target is your TableViewController, and the the SEL has an argument named sender, like this:

```
- (void)likeButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

then you can find the Cell View according to sender (sender.superView.....), and use the TableView to find the cell's index, that's all.